# Azure web app Exception [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, odbc

We are working on migrating old vb.net project to azure web app.
But web app uses ODBC connection to access sql database. Database has already been migrated to Azure SQL.
I am not able to find a way to create ODBC connection in Azure web app?

When the solution is deployed to Azure web app it throws error about ODBC:

> Azure web app Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specify the driver name in connection string.

Comment: Please refer [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/227987/34error-im002-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-so.html)